# Printing a JS variable in a value="" attribute

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm trying to implement a Paypal button with a dynamic value. When I enter, for example, value="300.00", the button works fine.

However, if I do it my way, the button doesn't work properly. The variable price is the JS variable that holds the information I need to put into the Paypal button.

Here's the line of code at fault:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<script>document.write(price)</script>.00">
```

Comment: This looks like a hidden field, not a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript:

```
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' + price + '">')
```

Or better yet

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' + price + '">';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DaczG/)**

Comment: What if the OP wants to update the input dynamically multiple times?

Comment: Correct, however it seems like the OP wants to create the input once only

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByName('amount')[0].value = price;
```

This will find the "button" and set its value to the value of the `price` variable. I assume that the "button" already is somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you have unclosed tags.

Notice here that you opened another tag without closing the other tag.

**<**input type="hidden" name="amount" value="***<*script

To achieve what you want, you need to `write` the entire block using JS

```
<script>
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' + price + '.00">');
</script>
```

Comment: I prefer Šime's solution to this because it doesn't introduce an XSS vulnerability when price is controlled by an attacker.  Consider what would happen if price could be `"><script>alert("OWNED")</script>`

Comment: Not enough information to comment on that. It could just be a straight numeric calculated elsewhere, since you control the script.